# Wordpress How to set subdir for API REST

Tags: wordpress, rest, api

I'm modifying a Wordpress site that at the beginning was made not by me.

Let's assume that the site is www.mysite.com
The home dir of wordpress (called in my case "clickandbuilds") contains:

- subdir "Api"; it contains a file called "api_function.php", and a file ".htaccess"; the file ".htaccess" contains the row: "RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /api_function.php?token=$1 [B,PT]"
- subdir "mysite"; it cointain all the Wordpress code

The site makes available some Rest API in this way:

- if I want to invoke an Api of the site, I put in the browser "http://api.mysite.com/xxxxx....
- When the site receives this Api request, the file "api_function.php" is runned and something is done according to the "xxxxxx...."

QUESTION:

Where is setted in Wordpress that, when an api request "api.mysite...." is received, it is looked inside the dir "Api" and runned "api_function.php"?

My target is to move this "Api" dir in another place, for example inside "mysite/test/Api/".

Thank you in Advance

Answer (score 0):

I solved by myself...

i simply discovered that "api.mysite.com" is a subdomain of www.mysite.com; the homedir of that subdomain is just the dir "Api".

When an http request "http://api.mysite.com/xxxxx...." arrives, the .htaccess file redirect to the "api_function.php" file.

That's all... Then I just changed (in the hosting control panel) the homedir from "...Api" to ".../other_dir/Api".